# Custom delete method refactoring

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and don't know all the methods, so I was thinking there would probably be and easier way to do something like this. I'd love any input on how to refactor this.

```
   define_singleton_method(:delete) do |id|
        revised_words = []
        @@words.each do |word|
          if word.id() != id
            revised_words.push(word)
          else
            Definition.delete_by_word_id(id)
          end
        end
        @@words = revised_words
      end
```

Comment: Please provide a more specific title.  "Delete method" sounds too generic.

Comment: Something like `delete word from wordlist`

Comment: Can you give us more information about the class on which the `delete` method will be added? Is this part of a module that gets included in other classes?

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- An array is not the best data structure to store the words, operations will be O(n). Better a hash `{word_id => word}`
- Use 2-space indentation.

Then you can write:

```
define_singleton_method(:delete) do |id|
  if @@words.delete(id)        
    Definition.delete_by_word_id(id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The method would benefit from functional programming:

```
@@words.select{|word| word.id == id}.each{|id| Definition.delete_word_by_id(id)}
@@words.select{|word| word.id != id}
```

Still I don't like that this method both has side effects and returns, it has too much responsability.